# Is there a contradiction between these two sources about the `auto_ptr` template class?

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

This [site](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm) states on "**Ownership, Sources, and Sinks**" :

"When you copy an `auto_ptr`, you automatically transfer ownership from the source `auto_ptr` to the target `auto_ptr`; **if the target `auto_ptr` already owns an object, that object is first freed**. After the copy, only the target `auto_ptr` owns the pointer and will delete it in due time, while the source is set back to a null state and can no longer be used to refer to the owned object.".

Now consider the definition of `operator=()` for the `templacte<classX> class auto_ptr`, in Chapter 14, page 368 of Stroustrup's *The C++ Programming Language Third Edition*:

`auto_ptr& operator=(auto_ptr& a) throw() { ptr = a.ptr; a.ptr = 0; }`

I can't see the operator freeing the object addressed by `ptr`, in case `ptr != 0` !

Comment: Something else suspicious: that `operator=` isn't returning anything.

Comment: @sbi The C++ Programming Language Third Edition

Comment: What's the type of `ptr`? Is that `classX*` or `auto_ptr_guts<classX>` ? If it's the latter, the code above would be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's definitely a bug in the latter piece of code. Object pointed to by `ptr` must be `delete`d before a new value is assigned to `ptr`, otherwise the object originally pointed to by `ptr` will be leaked.

Comment: Curiously, even in the errata (http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_printing5.html) the deletion is not mentioned.

Comment: @sharptooth: especially unused code bases - it's not as if the code in C++PL is being automatically extracted from the repository of a production implementation of `auto_ptr`.